# MySQL stored procedure regarding a call

Tags: mysql

I am new in programming and this is my first question in the forum. Can you explain me please in this code in MySQL why I get the result 3? I thought I would get 2. If I run again it increases every time by one. Thank you.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE uservariable()
BEGIN
SET @x = @x + 1;
SELECT @x;
END$$

SET @x = 1;
CALL uservariable();
CALL uservariable();
```

Comment: Why do you think you would get 2? It starts at 1, you increment it twice.

Answer (score 0):

`SET @x = @x + 1;`

This line increments `@x` value by one each time `uservariable()` procedure is called.

```
SET @x = 1; --@x value is 1 
CALL uservariable(); --@x value is 2
CALL uservariable(); --@x value is 3
```